# passing datetime and checkbox value to Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

am trying to pass two DateTime, and a Bool from a checkbox to my controller

Controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult TestParse(DateTime DateFrom, DateTime DateTo, bool active)
```

here is my razor view:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("TestParse", "Sags", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input type="checkbox" name="active">
    <input type="date" name="DateFrom">
    <input type="date" name="DateTo">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
}
```

it finds the controller, but it doesn't pass the values, they're all null execpt for active which is "true" how can i get the values of these?

Comment: Not possible - your checkbox does not have a value so it post `"on"` which could never bind to `bool active` so `active` would be `false`, not `true`. And your `DateTime` properties will bind fine based on the code you have shown, but again they cannot be `null` (the parameters are not nullable)

Comment: yes sorry @StephenMuecke i should have mentioned i tested by trying to allow nullable. But the bool always returned true for some reason. Thanks for the quick respond.

Comment: Nonsense. That is simply impossible based on the code you have shown (and why did you accept that answer which has nothing at all to do with your issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a view model to patch your fields together

```
public class SomeViewModel
{
    public DateTime DateFrom { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateTo { get; set; }

    public bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

The form

```
@model Namespace.SomeViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("TestParse", "Sags", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Active)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateFrom)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateTo)
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
}
```

And then in your controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult TestParse(SomeViewModel model)
```

You can use some js library to style your datepicker

Comment: How it in world does this address OP issue! If OP code does not work, then this does not work

Comment: I think this approach should solve the author's issue, because the model binder can't recognize the values from the form (I think). Also maybe an attribute [FromBody] before each of the method arguments could work

Comment: Use a view model is very good practice, but this has nothing to do with OP's question (and OP is making claims which are not possible so either they are mistaken or they have not shown the relevant code) - And `[FromBody]` is only applicable to web-api, not mvc

Comment: using this i fixed the issue, and got the data parsed, it may not be the solution i was looking for but it solved my problem.